# i can't check whether an evaluated variable in undefined

Tags: javascript, eval

I have the following code in which I want to eval a concatenation and then check whether it's defined or not,

```
var image1="images/pic1.png";
var image2="images/pic2.png";
var image3="images/pic3.png";
var image4="images/pic4.png";
/*
var image5="";
var image6="";
var image7="";
var image8="";
var image9="";
var image10="";
var image11="";
var image12="";
*/

var imageLink;
var count=12;

for (i=0;i<count;i++){

    var imageLink=eval("image"+(i+1));

    if (typeof imageLink === "undefined"){
        alert("imageLink is undefined");
        imageLink="";
    }
```

So the last piece doesn't work.

Comment: Just use arrays. `eval` here is questionable coding. One problem with this code is it will throw a ReferenceError. Compare `x` with `window.x`, where `x` is not set (and there are many duplicates about it).

Comment: wherever you use `eval` in your code, you should completely rewrite that piece of code instead of trying to fix the problems occuring.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = [];

images.push( 'images/pic1.png' );
images.push( 'images/pic2.png' );
images.push( 'images/pic3.png' );
images.push( 'images/pic4.png' );

var imageLink = '';

for ( i=0; i<images.length; i++ ){

    imageLink = images[ i ];

    if ( !imageLink ){
       alert( 'imageLink is undefined' );
       imageLink = '';
    }
}
```

as recommended in the comment, put the data on an array, and then cycle through each element on the for, this way your code gets cleaner and you don't have to do an eval.

Comment: no problem, PS: do accept the answers that are correct, I noticed your previous question was also without an accepted answer :)